# ¿Por qué no se usa el subjuntivo en "La dependienta mira... y no puede creer lo que *oye* a continuación"?

Tags: subjuntivo, indicativa

En *El juego de té* de Eulàlia Solé, ¿hay algún motivo por el que no se  usa el subjuntivo aquí?

> Ahora es Jaime quien se ha echado a reír. La dependienta mira a los dos entre molesta y sorprendida. Y no puede creer lo que **oye** a continuación.

¿Es que duda lo que no puede creer y por tanto es indicativo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Que oye algo es un hecho.  Lo que no cree es el contenido de lo que oye.

Si fuera algo tipo «y no puede creer que oiga...» (y entonces el hecho de que oye algo se pone en duda), el subjuntivo sería preciso.

Answer (score 5):

Cuando se usa *creer* más una oración subordinada (*creer que…*) existen varios casos en que debe utilizarse el subjuntivo. Pero éste no es uno de esos casos, porque *«lo que oye»* se refiere a algo que la dependienta está oyendo realmente; no es hipotético ni dudoso.

Son diferentes

1. *creer (en) algo* y
2. *creer que algo pasó.*

La dependienta no puede (1) creer (en) lo que oye (le parece increíble, que no puede ser cierto, que no ha escuchado bien), pero sí sabe que oye (2); no está en duda que ha oído. La **acción** de oír es real, y por lo tanto va en indicativo. Es el **contenido** de lo que oye lo que la dependienta no puede creer.

Distinto sería un caso como el siguiente:

> *No debes creer (nada de) lo que oigas.*

En este caso sí se usaría el subjuntivo, porque estamos hablando de algo que el oyente podría hipotéticamente oír en el futuro.